# DOM extension on PHP 7.2 Amazon Linux 2

Tags: php, symfony-2.8, php-7.2, amazon-linux

I'm getting the error message below from a Symfony 2.8 application running PHP 7.2.8 on an Amazon Linux 2 server.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Extension DOM is required. in /var/www/html/my-app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Util/XmlUtils.php:45
```

php-xml is installed. Other common/related libraries are installed too - php-mbstring, php-common.

In phpinfo, I cannot see the "DOM" section. Below is the screen shot of the installed php-related libraries (yum list installed | grep php*)

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After 2 days of nit-picking it turned out restarting php-fpm resolves the issue, though I was restarting httpd all along.

```
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
```

Comment: I was having this same issue. Cheers for actually answering your own question when you found the solution.

Comment: Thank you, I was going crazy with this problem

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify the extension is enabled in your `php.ini`? Did yyou happen to install the correct version of `php-xml`? I had a few issues while installing PHP 7.x and installing extensions. It installed 5.6 extensions instead of 7.x when no version is specified.

Try these commands

To list all modules:

```
php -m
```

And/or to list the detailed configuration:

```
php -i
```

Check the output for the php-xml extension and if it is loaded.

I read that maybe`php-mbstring` has to be installed too. But i am not too sure of this, altough i usually have it installed.

Comment: Yes here's the output of "php -i" for xml: XML Support => active. XML Namespace Support => active. libxml2 Version => 2.9.1

Answer (score 0):

In CentOS (and RHEL, i suppose) PHP module (extension) dom is provided by

```
php74-php-xml
```

https://centos.pkgs.org/7/remi-x86_64/php74-php-xml-7.4.11-1.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm.html

```
php74-php-dom
php74-php-domxml
php74-php-simplexml
php74-php-xml   = 7.4.11-1.el7.remi
php74-php-xmlreader
php74-php-xmlwriter
php74-php-xsl
```